# How to apply function to multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes:

```
df1, df2, df3,..., dfn
```

They have the same type of data but from different groups of descriptors that cannot be joined. Now I need to apply the same function to each dataframe manually.

How can I apply the same function to multiple dataframes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data frames have the same columns you could [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them to a single data frame, but otherwise there is not really a "smart" way of doing it:

```
df1, df2, df3 = (df.apply(...) for df in [df1, df2, df3]) # or either .map or .applymap
```

Comment: Isn't the method name applymap (instead of mapapply)? I often forget myself, but my IDEs rarely ;-)

Comment: I can't 'concat' data frames because they are difference type of data but all data frames need to do exactly the same workflow.

Comment: It do not work, so is anything wrong
'def unique(df):
    df['bioactivity_type'].unique()
df1, df2, df3 = (df.apply(unique) for df in [df1, df2, df3])'

KeyError: ('bioactivity_type', u'occurred at index activity_comment')

Answer (score 8):

#### [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) + comprehension

If your dataframes contain related data, as in this case, you should store them in a `list` (if numeric ordering is sufficient) or `dict` (if you need to provide custom labels to each dataframe). Then you can [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) each dataframe through a function `foo` via a comprehension.

#### List example

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_list = [df.pipe(foo) for df in df_list]
```

Then access your dataframes via `df_list[0]`, `df_list[1]`, etc.

#### Dictionary example

```
df_dict = {'first': df1, 'second': df2, 'third': df3}
df_dict = {k: v.pipe(foo) for k, v in df_dict.items()}
```

Then access your dataframes via `df_dict['first]`, `df_dict['second']`, etc.