# Apply function to multiple pandas data frames without having to access them by name afterwards

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

Leading on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243556/how-to-apply-function-to-multiple-pandas-dataframe), I have an arbitrary number of dataframes

```
df1, df2, df3,..., dfn
```

and I need to apply the same function to each of them. Since I do not know how many data frames there will be, none of the answers apply to my use case, as they involve accessing each data frames via `df_list[0], df_list[1]`, etc. or `df_dict['first'], df_dict['second']`, etc. afterwards.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is you question "how to loop over the elements of a list/dictionary"?

Comment: How are you getting your dataframes?

Comment: Are your dataframes part of a list or dictionary? Are they stand alone variables in code, if so, then add them to a list or dictionary and loop to apply your function to each element of that dictionary/list.

Comment: @mozway Seems sarcastic but no

Comment: That wasn't sarcastic. You shouldn't create many dataframes initially, instead store them in a list/dictionary upon creation. See the linked duplicate.